# Replace Lockscreen Wallpaper in Lollipop 5.0.1

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've recently upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S4 (i9505) LTE to Lollipop 5.0.1 and I've noticed there is nowhere to change the lockscreen wallpaper, so now I'm stuck with the chess-piece background that comes with the black edition BTU firmware that I've loaded onto the device. Is there anyway to change it without replacing the default lockscreen with an app? Surely there's a location on the device that the image exists in which I can just manually replace it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the lockscreen background in Galaxy S4 lollipop from below path from user perspective:

> Goto Homescreen (press HOME key) -> press Menu key (left side key to
>   Home key) -> Select Wallpaper -> Select Lockscreen from drop down at
>   top -> Select option Gallery -> Change image

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I was looking in Settings > My Device > Display > Wallpaper - but there is only the option for the main wallpaper in there.

Answer (score 1):

The select lockscreen option does not exist on many devices/versions. If that's your case, you might want to open your "Gallery" app, choose the photo you want to set as wallpaper en choose "Set as" option in photo settings. Then you will get an option to set it as wallpaper, screen lock or both. Choose whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **NOVA LAUNCHER**, you must disable it first. Use default Android Launcher, go to Settings - Display - Wallpaper - Change for both (Home Screen and Lock Screen). Tested on Nexus 5X (Android 6.x/7.x).

You can also use this "**[Private Photo Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msd.photoviewer)**" to change wallpaper without messing with launchers, but it works from Android N higger only!